# Extract server certificate from PCKS12

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I have a p12 file which apparently contains the server certificate. I need to extract the x509 server certificate from the p12 file so that I can add it to my java trust store, the problem is that I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Java supports PKCS#12 format keystores natively, and in fact current versions recommend using PCKS#12 as the default keystore format.

If you need to export individual certificates, you can also use Java's keystore management tool:

```
keytool -keystore server.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -list

keytool -keystore server.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -exportcert -alias 1 -file server.crt
```

The output file will contain the X.509 certificate in DER format – but not the private key.

---

You can also export the private key using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -out server.pem -nodes
```

The output file will contain both the X.509 certificate and the associated private key, both in PEM (base64) format.